# For loop not writing to list correctly?

Tags: python

I know this is basic stuff, i'm sure i must be just misunderstanding the loop here or missing a little trick, but why isn't this code working? The problem is invisible to me!

```
        

    print(itemclientprice_clean)
    
    for pu, cl in zip(itempurchaseprice_clean, itemclientprice_clean):

        if cl == '0.0':
            profit_list.append('0')
        else:
            profit = pu - cl
        profit_list.append(profit)


    print(profit_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

[129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0, 129000.0]
```

The second list should all be 0? However it's instead the value of the `else` statement.

Comment: ```profit_list.append(profit)```. Looks like the ```else``` statement performs an operation, changing the value of ```profit```, which you add to the list. Move ```profit_list.append(profit)
``` inside the ```if``` statement

Comment: `0.0` and `'0.0'` are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I am seeing is in your if statement. It's a common mistake, but don't confuse your *floats* and *Strings*!!

`'0.0'` is not the same as `0.0`

Also, just a side note, but I think you meant to append the profit to profit_list in your else statement, as profit is not defined:

```
print(itemclientprice_clean)

for pu, cl in zip(itempurchaseprice_clean, itemclientprice_clean):

    if cl == 0.0:
        profit_list.append('0')
    else:
        profit = pu - cl
        profit_list.append(profit)


print(profit_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably is matter of type. U check on string type over the float 0.0
From this :
if cl == '0.0':
To this:

```
    if cl == 0.0:
```

Check python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to be

```
0.0 == '0.0'
-> False
```

your client prices are numbers not strings so you comparison fails and you move to the else part in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code

1. you are comparing variables with difference datatype
2. you will append both `0.0` and the difference of `pu` and `cl` if `cl` is `0.0`

to fix them,

```
for pu, cl in zip(itempurchaseprice_clean, itemclientprice_clean):
    if cl == 0.0:         # '0.0' is not the same as 0.0, datatype matters too
        profit = 0.0      # if it is equal to 0, then append 0.0 to profit_list
    else:
        profit = pu - cl  # if not, then append the difference
    profit_list.append(profit) # append the decided profit to profit_list
print(profit_list)
```